# Oracle Select Where Date Between Today

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a Oracle SELECT Query like this:

```
Select * From Customer_Rooms CuRo
   Where CuRo.Date_Enter Between 'TODAY 12:00:00 PM' And 'TODAY 11:59:59 PM'
```

I mean, I want to select all where the field "date_enter" is today. I already tried things like `Trunc(Sysdate) || ' 12:00:00'` in the between, didn't work.

**Advice:** I can't use TO_CHAR because it gets too slow.

Comment: You're only selecting things in the afternoon there, you know. 12pm is noon. Typically to compare dates without times you'd just truncate them both (And do you actually need the time in the table? Storing it truncated in the first place will probably make things faster and easier.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming `date_enter` is a `DATE` field:

```
Select * From Customer_Rooms CuRo
   Where CuRo.Date_Enter >= trunc(sysdate)
   And CuRo.Date_Enter < trunc(sysdate) + 1;
```

The `trunc()` function strips out the time portion by default, so `trunc(sysdate)` gives you midnight this morning.

If you particularly want to stick with `between`, and you have a `DATE` not a `TIMESTAMP`, you could do:

```
Select * From Customer_Rooms CuRo
   Where CuRo.Date_Enter between trunc(sysdate)
      And trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day - interval '1' second;
```

`between` is inclusive, so if you don't take a second off then you'd potentially pick up records from exactly midnight tonight; so this generates the 23:59:59 time you were looking for in your original query. But using `>=` and `<` is a bit clearer and more explicit, in my opinion anyway.

If you're sure you can't have dates later than today anyway, the upper bound isn't really adding anything, and you'd get the same result with just:

```
Select * From Customer_Rooms CuRo
   Where CuRo.Date_Enter >= trunc(sysdate);
```

You don't want to use `trunc` or `to_char` on the `date_enter` column though; using any function prevents an index on that column being used, which is why your query with `to_char` was too slow.

Comment: That's what I'd do. Well, the first bit, anyway. I don't like code that does things to 23:59:59—some databases have time types with resolutions where that could miss things (e.g. 23:59:59.43) Will this be faster than truncating both dates as in GR Envoy's answer? Or is Oracle smart enough to use the index anyway?

Comment: Oracle won't use an index if you apply a function to the column; so `trunc(CuRo.Date_Enter)` wouldn't use the index, no. I don't think the optimiser is quite clever enough to have a special case for `trunc`.

Comment: Yup, that was my suspicion. +1.

Comment: That answer appears to be gone.  However, oracle will not use indexes on function results.   Go with the 1st code snippet in this answer.

Comment: @Alex, it DID work. Thanks!!

I used the "Select * From Customer_Rooms CuRo
   Where CuRo.Date_Enter >= trunc(sysdate)
   And CuRo.Date_Enter < trunc(sysdate) + 1", because Date_Enter will be never tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: anyone achieved this on JPA repo without @Query (statement)
I am currently using TRUNC(date) = to_date(:dateString, 'YY-MM-DD')

Comment: @ThanasisNamikazee - this is an 8-year-old question... ask a new question showing your current code (with real, or at least legal, identifiers), data and issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was searching trough some log files and wanted to find only the ones that happened TODAY.

For me, it didn't matter what time it happened, just had to be today, so:

```
/*...*/
where
    trunc(_DATETIMEFROMSISTEM_) = trunc(sysdate)
```

It works perfectly for this scenario.

Comment: Fine if you have an index on trunc(\_DATETIMEFROMSISTEM\_), but an index on \_DATETIMEFROMSISTEM\_ would not be used for this.

Comment: Hate the column name btw :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can write query like this

```
select * from table_name where last_time<=CURRENT_TIME() and last_date<=CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: Not really: `ORA-00904: "CURRENT_TIME": invalid identifier`

Answer (score -2):

Try the below code

```
Select * From Customer_Rooms CuRo
   Where trunc(CuRo.Date_Enter) = 'TODAY' -- TODAY is the date of today without any timestamp.
```

Comment: `sysdate` has the current time, so `trunc(CuRo.Date_Enter) = sysdate` will only find records if you run it exactly at midnight. Not sure what `TODAY` is; if it's a date like 01/08/2014 then you'd be relying on implicit conversion? And truncating the column value stops any index on that being used.

Comment: You've removed the sysdate part that someone else also got wrong, but the `trunc` on the column is still potentially a performance problem, and it isn't very clear what `TODAY` actually is.

Comment: @AlexPoole I removed the sysdate code as well about TODAY query function based indexing will work fine.

Comment: True, you could add an FBI for `trunc(date_enter)`, but you could mention that in the answer? So is `'TODAY'` representing `trunc(sysdate)`?